# Assimp Skeletal Animation : Bones associated with a Vertex

Tags: opengl, assimp, skeletal-mesh

I am trying to integrate the Assimp skeletal animation. Following this [tutorial](http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/www/tutorial38/tutorial38.html)  for reference.
The change I am trying is to use fixed function pipeline.

**Problem**: Position, Texture Coordinates and Normal Data is fine, but I cannot figure out how the four bones and the weight data is obtained for each vertex as mentioned in the tutorial.
[image: Vertex Data]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the illustration in the tutorial is quite clear on that:

[image]

Comment: Please refer the code snippet in my other question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24599637/visual-artifacts-when-loading-obj-model-with-assimp]. I am looking for the "//Storing the Bones" code